# EPPlus - Read to object

Tags: c#, epplus

How can I read excel file with template like below,
I have an object inside that has a list object with a 1-n . relationship

[image: Excel file]

```
public class TestObject
{
    [Column(1)]
    public int Col1 { get; set; }

    [Column(2)]
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
    [Column(3)]
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
    [Column(4)]
    public DateTime Col4 { get; set; }

    public List<SubClass> List1 { get; set; }

    public List<SubCl> List2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general logic could be something like this...

```
public void ParseSheet(ExcelWorksheet ws)
    {
        for (int r = 1; r <= ws.Dimension.Rows; r++)
        {
            var col1 = int.Parse(ws.Cells[r, 1].Value.ToString()); // can be improved
            // ... add more single values
            var list1 = new List<int>();
            list1.Add(int.Parse(ws.Cells[r, 9].Value.ToString())); // adapt to real need
            list1.Add(int.Parse(ws.Cells[r, 10].Value.ToString()));
            // ... add more list entries
        }
    }
```

Getting a typed value from a cell can be a bit tricky, as cells contain objects that could be null. So be careful with parsing the entries. The code shown above is not robust enough for production.

Comment: Thanks you @lzydrmr, but it is not an common function.

Comment: Yes, you would have to adapt and extend it to your needs... it's not a complete program to address your requirement.